# How to map twice using Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to create a table similar to how it's shown [here](https://www.figaro.lt/) ("Paslaugos" section), and allow the client to change table content using WordPress.

So I looped through, and displayed images and titles, without issue. However, I can't figure it out how to display table items. How do you map items twice in this context?

**Update**

```
{node.acf.table_items.header.map(({ c }) => (
 <span>{c}</span>
))}

{node.acf.table_items.body[0].map(({ c }) => (
  <span>{c}</span>
 ))}
```

So I kinda figure it out. This way would display header, but display only first item in the table. I need to loop `body[0]` in order to work, however I can't figure it out the exact syntax.

So thanks to ZeroToMastery forum the correct answer would be this:

```
{node.acf.table_items.body.map(mappingBody => {
  return mappingBody.map(({ c, index }) => {
    return (
     <span key={index} className={classes.body}>
       {c}
     </span>
    )
  })
})}
```

**Current Result**
[image]

```
<StaticQuery
            query={graphql`
              {
                allWordpressPost(
                  filter: {
                    categories: { elemMatch: { name: { eq: "favours" } } }
                  }
                ) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id
                      acf {
                        favours_title
                        table_items {
                          body {
                            c
                          }
                          header {
                            c
                          }
                        }
                        favours_images {
                          localFile {
                            childImageSharp {
                              fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            `}
            render={data =>
              data.allWordpressPost.edges.map(({ node }) => (
                <div key={node.id} className={classes.item}>
                  <Img
                    className={classes.img}
                    fluid={
                      node.acf.favours_images.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid
                    }
                  />
                  <h2 className={classes.title}>{node.acf.favours_title}</h2>
                  <div className={classes.grid}>
                    {node.acf.table_items.header.map(({ header }) => (
                      <span>{header}</span>
                    ))}
                    {node.acf.table_items.body.map(({ body }) => (
                      <span>{body}</span>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Zero To Mastery forum, the correct answer would be this:

```
{node.acf.table_items.body.map(mappingBody => {
  return mappingBody.map(({ c, index }) => {
    return (
      <span key={index} className={classes.body}>
         {c}
      </span>
    )
  })
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that the data in `body` is a 2D nested array, e.g.

```
node.acf.table_items.body = [['row1-columnA', 'row1-columnB'], ['row2-columnA', 'row2-columnB']];
```

To map through each item in a 2D array, you could use `map()` twice:

```
{node.acf.table_items.body.map(c => c.map(el => (
  <span>{el}</span>
)))}
```

Or, if you know there are a set number of items in each sub-array, you could use target the specific elements using square bracket notation:

```
{node.acf.table_items.body.map(c => (
  <span>{c[0]}</span>
  <span>{c[1]}</span>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mapping twice doesn't work I get Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {c}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. The 3rd option is not viable for me, since this is supposed to allow client to add items using wordpress. If c[1] is not present it would crash the application.

Comment: Recently I discovered the correct answer I update my question